# I am in pain, what the heck!

Tags: riddle

> My favorite bird is the crane,
>   I’m no plumber, but I got pipes and drains.
>   Without a mirror, I’ve never seen your face,
>   I carry your world, but I am not in space.
>   A constant heavy burden I assist,
>   My favorite dance is the twist.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're a

> neck! Specifically, I think you're MY neck.

My favorite bird is the crane,

> You can *crane* your neck

I’m no plumber, but I got pipes and drains.

> Your neck has a windpipe, and an esophagus (which will drain down to your stomach.

Without a mirror, I’ve never seen your face,

> It would be rather difficult for a neck to see a face.

I carry your world, but I am not in space.

> Your neck carries your head (which contains your brain, and your consciousness, which would be your world).

A constant heavy burden I assist,

> Keeps your head up all day.

My favorite dance is the twist.

> You can twist your neck, though I admit I twist mine more often as a stretch than a dance move.

Title bonus

> Pain in the neck.

Comment: You got it! I was feeling it might be a bit too obvious but had fun coming up with it. Also, I pinched a nerve in my neck on Monday and I can't get it off my mind!